# Custom unregister_name/2 not being called on child termination

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor watching over a pool of supervisors, with a child spec similar to

```
init([]) ->                                                                                                                                                                                
    {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, 60, 5},                                                                                                                                                                      
          [{subsup, {subsup, start_link, []},                                                                                                                                        
            permanent, infinity, supervisor, dynamic}]}}.
```

My `start_child` func looks like this:

```
start_subsup(Name) ->
    SupName = {via, ?MODULE, Name},
    supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, [SupName]).
```

Here's the important part: I'm registering `via` the `?MODULE` -- I've properly implemented `register_name/2`, `unregister_name/1`, `whereis_name/1`, and `send/2` (backed by an ets table). If necessary, I can post that code also.

My child's start_link func looks like so:

```
start_link(SupName) ->
    supervisor:start_link(SupName, ?MODULE, []).
```

Alright, once everything is up and running something like the following will happen:

```
%% This returns a live pid. cool.    
Pid = sup:whereis_name(name),

%% I can terminate it, and it really dies
ok = supervisor:terminate_child(sup, Pid),
undefined = process_info(Pid),

%% But! it never calls unregister_name!?
Pid = sup:whereis_name(name).
```

I set all this up so that I can just let the child supervisor die and restart, but it's being blocked by the name not being unregistered.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not implementing the semantics correctly. `unregister_name/2` is only called on initialization to break a possible race condition. Otherwise, it is assumed that your ETS module sets a monitor on the registered name so it can automatically remove the name when the process terminates.

Look at `gproc` for a solution which is already done and more polished than yours.

Comment: Yup, that explains why I couldn't find it in the otp src. gproc looks like the right hammer -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to trap exit signals for a stopped child to run terminate.  Call this in your child process's `init`:

```
process_flag(trap_exit, true)
```

Comment: This is kind of problematic. Usually you don't want to trap exits in processes. Furthermore, in this case it will not help.

Comment: It says in the [documentation for gen_server](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:terminate-2) if you want `terminate` to be called when the supervisor tries to stop a process, you need to trap exits.  Are you saying that is bad practice?

Comment: There are two things to address. You should only trap exits if you *need* them trapped. This is rarely the case as another process can often do the cleanup, rather than having the crasher itself cleanup. So it is often a sign of badly designed application logic to have many `trap_exit` flags set in the code base. Furthermore, the problem here is about registration, and in that case the terminate code-path in the `gen_server` is never touched. So the flag will have absolutely no effect.

Comment: Ok, I think there's something about the supervisor I don't understand yet.  Thanks.